# Integer pair points on linear functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

It's possible I'm missing something obvious, but I'm struggling with a problem dealing with finding points on a line where both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are integers. Basically, given a line ($y=mx+b$) find one point on the line where both $x$ and $y$ are integers. It would be helpful to know in what cases this doesn't work as well. I think I know a few of them, for example $y=1.2x+0.1$ and $y=3x+0.5$ have no integer-integer pairings. The first one has no such pairings as the first decimal value will never be odd for any values of $x$, and therefore there will always be a $0.1$ hanging around. The second, since $x$ values are integers, would always be an integer $+ 0.5$, which will never be an integer.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: @HrishikeshVenkataraman could you clarify a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the equation is $y=mx+b$, where $m,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If either or both of $m$ and $b$ are irrational, then $mx+b$ would be irrational. Hence, the equation cannot have an integer pair as a solution.
Thus, we assume that $m,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. As a consequence, we have $m=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$ and $b=\frac{b_1}{b_2}$, where $m_1,m_2,b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m_2,b_2\neq 0$. Substituting these in the equation, we get $y=\frac{m_1}{m_2}x+\frac{b_1}{b_2}$. This equation can be converted into an equivalent equation of the form $px+qr=r$, where $p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is called a 'Linear Diophantine equation'.
A well-known result is that any equation of the above form has an integer solution if and only if $GCD(p,q)|r$ (i.e., the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $q$ divides $r$).
Once an equation satisfies the above condition, we can determine an integer solution. This can be done using the 'Extended Euclidean algorithm', which gives a solution to the equation $px+qy=GCD(p,q)$. Let $(x',y')$ be a solution. Since it satisfies the equation, we have $px'+qy'=GCD(p,q)$. Multiply the whole equation by $c=\frac{r}{GCD(p,q)}$. This gives $cpx'+cqx'=c\cdot GCD(p,q)$ or equivalently, $p(cx')+q(cy')=r$. Thus, $(cx',cy')$ is a solution to $px+qy=r$.

Comment: $m=b=\sqrt2$, $x=-1$, $y=0$ is a counterexample to your first assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hrishikesh Venkatarman!

@GerryMyerson So, $y = 0$ for irrational $b$ and $m$ given the following?

$b = b_1b_2$ where $b_1$ is the rational coefficient to simplified $b$, and $b_2$ is the irrational part.
$m = m_1m_2$ where $m_1$ is the rational coefficient to simplified $m$, and $m_2$ is the irrational part.

The new function, $y = b_1b_2x + m_1m_2$ is $0$ when $b_1 = \frac{m_1}{|x|}$ and $b_2 = m_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the irrational part". There is no canonical way to write an irrational as the product of a rational part and an irrational part.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There is? Consider $\sqrt{8}$. Multiply out for $\sqrt{4}\sqrt{2}$, and simplify. $2\sqrt{2}$ is still irrational, by definition. For irrational numbers that can't be simplified in this way, like just $\pi$, it would just be rational $1$ and irrational $\pi$. Of course, let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: So for most irrational $\alpha$ it would just be rational $1$ and irrational $\alpha$. Doesn't strike me as a terribly useful concept. What would it be for $1+\sqrt8$? or $\sqrt8+\sqrt{27}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's right, my bad. I was trying to account for irrational $m$ and $b$ where they weren't equal but the equation would still return $0$. For example, $m=\sqrt{2}, x=-4, b=4\sqrt{2}, y=0$. I realize though that.... adding irrationals retains the status as an irrational number, which I guess I didn't think of before, somehow? There's always something like this: $1 + \sqrt{8} = \sqrt{(1+\sqrt{8})^2} = \sqrt{9+2\sqrt{8}}$, but the usefulness is questionable.